# Unable to send message from client to server

Tags: c++, qt

I am developing an application where i need to send message from client to server and notify server if there are changes in files on client.
I am using QTcpServer and QTcpSocket class in Qt ..I am writing on socket and reading from socket on server side but my read fails.

Can i know how to post a message to server. I need implementation in Qt and C++..

Thanks in advance

Code on client side for writing :

QByteArray block;
        QDataStream out(&block, QIODevice::ReadWrite);
        out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_0);//statusLabel->setText(fortunes);
        getFortuneButton->setEnabled(true);
    //! [4] //! [6]
        out << (quint16)0;
        out << fortunes.at(qrand() % fortunes.size());
        out.device()->seek(0);
        out << (quint16)(block.size() - sizeof(quint16));
    //! [6] //! [7]

```
    tcpSocket->connectToHost("172.31.28.140",1331,QIODevice::ReadWrite);
    qint64 t = tcpSocket->write(block);
```

Code on server side:
QDataStream in(clientConnection);
    in.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_0);
    QString nextFortune;
    in >> nextFortune;
    statusLabel->setText(nextFortune);
    qDebug()<canReadLine();
    connect(clientConnection, SIGNAL(disconnected()),
        clientConnection, SLOT(deleteLater()));

Comment: We probably need a good bit more information to hazard a useful guess. Like, what code are you using to send/receive?

Comment: Please re-format your code properly. This is hardly readable.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example of client-server application coming with QT. Take a look at it

PS: format your text